# Uncaught Error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit' not found

Tags: php, composer-php

After attempting to remove and reinstall a package I'm getting this new error when I try to `include('vendor/autoload.php');`

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class >'ComposerAutoloaderInit7b3c839efeba468a3d595a365ceb8e89' not found in >mypath\vendor\autoload.php:7 Stack trace: #0 mypath\mypage.php(2): include() >#1 {main} thrown in mypath\vendor\autoload.php on line 7

I've tried running `composer clearcache` before and after reinstalling the package. I deleted `C:/Users/MyUsername/AppData/Roaming/Composer` and even completely uninstalled Composer. After I reinstalled composer and *then* reinstalled the package, the error message remains.

What am I missing? I feel like it has a hidden cache somewhere that's breaking this.

Comment: @betelgeuse not sure what you expect to accomplish by putting a bounty on a poor quality question like this? Would have been a better idea to post your own question with proper debugging details and an explanation of what you did to attempt to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your autoloader seems to be on an unfit state.

Just regenerate it.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

If this doesn't work (although it should), simply remove the whole `vendor` directory, and run `composer install` again.

Clearing composer's cache has no effect on this, since this is only the one used by composer to avoid downloading files all over again, not a project level cache.

Comment: That did it, thank you! Even though I was completely emptying the vendor folder and it was recreating the autoload already, this command fixed it.

Comment: I found that just doing `composer dump-autoload` didn't do the trick when I was in the situation. I also had to `composer clear-cache`.